# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method error

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, momentjs

Help would be much appreciated.

When I run the below I get a:

```
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'Moment'.
```

I get this in two parts of the code. The main bit that i'm concerned about is the isBefore line. As that's what I'm actually trying to do, so it's important. The other bit that (I get a similar error to the above) was added during efforts to figure out what the issue was, the "if (currrentTime.isValid)" check.

Also, initially this was just "value.isBefore(currentTime)" but that didn't seem to work..

The javascript is an external script. Am I not importing moment correctly??

```
src = "moment.js";


var currentTime = moment().format('DD MMMM YYYY');


var format = function (index, data) {

var value = data[index];
    if (currentTime.isValid())
    {
        if (index === 4 && value.Moment().isBefore.format(currentTime))                 {        
            return 'In the past - ' + value;
        }
        alert("currentTime not valid...")
    }
    return value;
}

} )
```

Comment: which browser you are using ? IE ? then which version ?

Comment: Not sure what value is as an example of 'data' isn't provided, but is this meant to be: moment(value).isBefore.format(currentTime)) ?

Comment: I've tried IE 11 in dev mode, which is working fine (except due this error it's not displaying/running). Also switching to firefox this displays my page but all the js seem to fail.

Apologies! data is just an array of strings that I'm using as just to populate my datatable after all this (which works fine). It was a lot to include, but i implemented it based on http://jsfiddle.net/9zr6z70g/3/ (so it's very similar).

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on how to import for this example moment.js into an external file. I assume as I have above? "src = "moment.js";"

Comment: `src = "moment.js"` just creates a variable called `src` that holds that string. Why would it import anything? (Normally one would simply include the moment.js file with a separate script element in your html, included before other scripts that need to use it. There are ways to import a library from within a script, but too hard to explain in a comment. Are you using any script management tools?)

Comment: Using visual studio. However, it's very much happy with it until I run/debug the html. Then it raises the error above.

Comment: So I'm correct in thinking that I import moment in my html. And nothing further is required to import moment? (I "think" isBefore is a moment method). But I'm totally confused why it isn't picking it up (assuming thats what the error is saying).